# ZPL: Multiple SGD (Get) in the Same Request

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to send, in one request, a get, a label to print, then another get.

1) Is this possible?
2) If so, what is the syntax?

Closest I've come so far is the following:

```
! U1 getvar "odometer.total_label_count"\n^XA Label Goes Here ^XZ\n! U1 getvar "odometer.total_label_count"
```

To clarify: I need to get the label count, print the label, then get the updated label count in one request. The code I have just returns the same count twice.

Am I just missing something or is this just not possible?

Comment: You can´t mix SGD and ZPL commands in the same file

Comment: Check this https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the label is getting queued to be printed. While it is getting printed your second SGD is processed. You would need to add a delay to do this.

You could register for the print job completed alert and then have that trigger your follow up odometer check.